# Hibernate Unknown Entity error with SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sql-server-2012

I am new to Hibernate, I am trying to connect it to SQL Server 2012. 
I am trying to apply the hello world example in this topic

http://www.java2blog.com/2013/01/hibernate-hello-world-example-in-eclipse.html

It wasn't working at the beginning, but after search in Stack Overflow, I successfully get it connected to SQL Server 2012. 
But I am still having an issue in mapping between my created class "User" with the database.

Here is my Configuration file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
 <property name = "hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
 <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
 <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://KAREEM-LAPTOP;databaseName=Hibernate;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;</property>
 <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
 <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">DFKI123</property>
 <property name = "hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>  
<mapping class="org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.User" table="User"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The User Class

```
package org.arpit.javapostsforlearning;  

import javax.persistence.Column;  

import javax.persistence.Entity;  
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;  


@Entity(name="User")
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {  

 @Id
 int userId;  

 @Column(name="User_Name")  
 String userName;

 @Column(name="userMessage")  
 String userMessage;  


 public int getUserId() {  
  return userId;  
 }  

 public void setUserId(int userId) {  
  this.userId = userId;  
 }  

 public String getUserName() {  
  return userName;  
 }  

 public void setUserName(String userName) {  
  this.userName = userName;  
 }  

 public String getUserMessage() {  
  return userMessage;  
 }  

 public void setUserMessage(String userMessage) {  
  this.userMessage = userMessage;  
 }  

}
```

Hibernate Main Class

```
package org.arpit.javapostsforlearning;  

import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; 
import org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.*;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;  
//import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;


public class HibernateMain {  

 public static void main(String[] args) {  

  Configuration configuration=new Configuration(); 
  configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");  

  ServiceRegistry sr= new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();  
  SessionFactory sf=configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);  


  User user1=new User(); 
  user1.setUserId(1);
  user1.setUserName("Arpit");  
  user1.setUserMessage("Hello world from arpit");  

  User user2=new User();  
  user2.setUserId(2);
  user2.setUserName("Ankita");  
  user2.setUserMessage("Hello world from ankita");  
  Session ss=sf.openSession();  
  ss.beginTransaction();  
 //saving objects to session  
  ss.save(user1);  
  ss.save(user2);  
  ss.getTransaction().commit();  
  ss.close();  

 }  

}
```

It is working fine and I got an info that Schema export complete

But after that I got an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.User

I have tried to follow several topic talking about the same issue, but no one worked with me, all topics were related to annotations but I did all of their recommendations without any hope.

I tried also to add Mapping section into the configuration file as per this article 
[Hibernate unknown entity error when saving new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828093/hibernate-unknown-entity-error-when-saving-new-object)

but it didn't work too,

What might cause this issue?

Comment: It's enough to use `@Entity` and `@Table` (without name) because you don't change it (it is `User` by default). Regarding the mapping, the following line `<mapping class="org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.User" table="User"></mapping>` could be changed to `<mapping class="org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.User"/>`.

Comment: You can try to change the `User` name to `UserType` because some words are reserved in SQL or just add a different name for `@Table` if you don't want to change your Java code too much. E.g.: `@Table(name="USER_TABLE")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from `create` to `update` on this line:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

@Entity shouldn't have any parameter as shown below:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "User")
    public class User {
```

Also, make sure that the table name in the database is exactly the same as you declared inside annotations. I hope you can solve it this way.

Comment: I did, but the same issue still exist.

Comment: Is the table name in the database called User, or user?

Comment: "User" as the name of the class